# how to export and save a file fetching name from database and contains "/" in its name c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winforms application.In this application I am exporting text file to my local machine and path is coming from database which is like "C:\MyFIles".

Now my problem is that I am exporting such file that has a "/" (forward slash) 
in between its name like `"ABC/DEF/Testing"`. So when i am 
exporting this file to my local machine its giving 
error like `"C:\\MyFiles\\ABC/DEF/Testing.text"` does not 
exist or check the specified path is exist.

I am stuck in this problem.Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Filenames can't have forward slashes in them - replace them with another character like an underscore (`_`)

Comment: Are you wanting a file called `ABC/DEF/Testing.text` or a file called `Testing.txt` that is in the `ABC\DEF` directory?

Comment: "/" is a directory separator (usable in .NET, Java, etc. but not in cmd.exe and many other contexts). It can never be in a file name.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Filenames can;t have forward slashes in them.  Replace them with another character like an underscore (`_`):

```
fileName = fileName.Replace("/","_");
```

Or to replace *all* invalid characters:

```
string invalidChars = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars());

foreach (char c in invalidChars)
{
    fileName = fileName.Replace(c.ToString(), ""); 
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Use any character in the current code page for a name, including
>   Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set
>   (128–255), except for the following:
>
> - The following reserved characters:

```
     < (less than)
     > (greater than)
     : (colon)
     " (double quote)
     / (forward slash)
     \ (backslash)
     | (vertical bar or pipe)
     ? (question mark)
     * (asterisk)
```

> - Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.
> - Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters are allowed. For more information about file streams, see File Streams.
> - Any other character that the target file system does not allow.

Comment: Also from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx): "The array returned from this method is not guaranteed to contain the complete set of characters that are invalid in file and directory names. "

Answer (score 1):

`/` is not working with filenames. Try replace them with `\` with

```
String yournivalidPath = "C:\\MyFiles\\ABC/DEF/Testing.text" ;
String validPath = yournivalidPath.Replace("/", "\\") ;
```